# Html.EditorFor how to make textbox active on page load

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, usability

I am working on a site in ASP.NET MVC and I have multiple Html.EditorFor form textboxes. The simple user friendly action I would like to do is on page load, the first of the textboxes on my view page is "active" or the user does not have to click on the textbox to start typing. There are pages like the login or other pages with only these forms where having to click to start typing is not intuitive and breaks the users experience.

Example form:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaxBid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

I am not finding any documentation for how to accomplish this, but it seems like it could be a simple fix. Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: I think it is just TextBoxName.setfocus()  do this in page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `autofocus` to the elment.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MaxBid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = true } })
```